# leetcode- c answer error of heap-use-after-free

Tags: c

I am new to C.I give the answer of question 20 of leetcode.I implement the stack to solve the problem.I want to know where I am wrong.I get some information about the error.It's said to be there is a memory leak.I have checked and can't figure it out.
The code is as follows:

```
    struct linestack{
    char element;
    struct linestack *next;
};

struct linestack *push(struct linestack *head,char c);
char pop(struct linestack *head);

bool isValid(char* s) {
    char *p = s;
    char c;
    struct linestack* head;
    while(*p!='\0'){
        if(*p=='('||*p=='{'||*p=='['){
            head = push(head,*p);
        }else{
            if(head)
                 c = pop(head);
            else
                return false;
            if(*p=='('&&c!=')')
                return false;
            if(*p=='['&&c!=']')
                return false;
            if(*p=='{'&&c!='}')
                return false;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return true;
}


struct linestack* push(struct linestack *head,char c){
    struct linestack* line = (struct linestack*)malloc(sizeof(struct linestack));
    line->element = c;
    line->next = head;
    head = line;
    return head;
}

char pop(struct linestack *head){
    char res;
    if(head){
        struct linestack* p = head;
        res = head->element;
        head = head->next;
        free(p);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x6020000001b0 at pc 0x00000040171c bp 0x7ffff6ca1190 sp 0x7ffff6ca1188
```

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the information.

Comment: In `pop` the new value of `head` is visible only within that function, but not from the caller (it is passed by value). The caller will get `head` `free`d

Comment: Thank you.I write a short program to validate what you say.You'are right.The pointer of argv is not changed after a function.In this problem,as head has been free.The pop will get head free.Than you sincerely!